# std::stoull but with string_view

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a `std::stoull` which takes a `basic_string_view`? I don't want to construct a string just to call `std::stoull`, especially since it takes it by `const &`.

If none exists, what is an efficient way to convert a `std::basic_string_view` to `unsigned long long`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for more efficiency, C++17 introduced [lower-level conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) in `<charconv>` ([live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b7ePbh)):

```
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
    const auto str = "2048"sv;

    unsigned long long result;
    auto [ptr, err] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), result);

    if (err == std::errc{} && ptr == str.data() + str.size()) {
        std::cout << "Entire conversion successful: " << result;
    }
}
```

The reason I don't use `str.begin()` and `str.end()` is because the API works directly on `const char*`, not iterators.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) explains why:

> `stoull` ... calls `std::strtoull(str.c_str(), &ptr, base)`

which requires a nul-terminated string (which `std::string_view` does not promise to provide).

Note, however, that `std::string` has a converting constructor that takes a `string_view` so you can write:

```
auto ull = std::stoull (std::string (my_string_view));
```

which is probably as good a solution as any.

Comment: What would an implementation of `stoull` using `string_view` look like, then?

Comment: @lajoh90686 I guess it would have to copy the characters on the string view to a nul-terminated string internally and then call `strtoull`.

Comment: What about my own `strtoull` but using `string_view` size instead of `strlen`?

Comment: Added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: It's performance-critical code, I can't just construct a string.

Comment: Why do you consider that so expensive?  You have to allocate space for a nul-terminated string somewhere and with small-string optimisation that may end up on the stack.

Comment: @lajoh90686 "*What about my own `strtoull` but using `string_view` size instead of `strlen`?*" - that would be one option, if you want to go to the trouble of writing such a function. Otherwise, another option would be to simply copy the `string_view`'s characters into a (thread)local `char[]` array, and then pass that to `strtoull()`. The maximum number of `char`s you would need to copy for parsing an `unsigned long long` value is 21 (20 digits + null-terminator).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Might want to use just local (not thread-) just in case re-entrancy is needed. That's not a lot for a local variable.